# AWS Elastic Beanstalk to run Flask web application via Ubuntu instead of Amazon Linux

Tags: python, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

As listed [here on official site](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.python#concepts.platforms.python), the operating system to host Python applications using AWS Elastic Beanstalk is Amazon Linux.

I wonder if possible to host under Ubuntu Server?

Comment: You will have to use a docker deployment, and then use any docket image you want

Comment: I'll try and back to u later